# Event Listener Best Practices for web app

Tags: javascript, web-applications, event-listener

I'm making a web app, and my javascript is collecting quite a few $(document).on event listeners. It is working well enough for me, but it feels like there is must be a better way to organize it. Here's a sample:

```
    // send quiz info via Ajax, then load form for the first question.
    $(document).on('click', '#create-new-quiz', function(){
        createNewQuiz();
        $('#forms').load("dash/workspace.php", {
            action : 'get-new-question'
        });
    }); 

    // load the form to create the first question
    $(document).on('click', '#finish-quiz', function(){
        addQuestion();
        $('#forms').load("dash/workspace.php",{
            action : 'finish-quiz'
        });
    }); 

    //call function to add a new question via ajax when the button is clicked. 
    $(document).on('click', '#add-question', function(){
        nextAction = "add-question";
        addQuestion();
    });
```

That shows that I have a variety of buttons that are dynamically added and removed form the DOM. When they are clicked, a function is called.

Any suggestions? Am I already on the right path, or is there a better way to organize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the `$('#button').click(function(){})` shortcut to be tidier.

Also, your first two event handlers are fairly similar and could be made a bit more generic i.e. passed an action as a variable:

```
$('.quizButton').click(function(e){
    createNewQuiz();
    $('#forms').load("dash/workspace.php", {
        action : $('this').data('action');
    });
});
```

Comment: I did try the .click() format, but it wasn't working. I think that was because the buttons aren't all there when the page loads. Changing to $(document).on solved it. I like the suggestion of using data tags for the .load() calls though. Thanks!